# Canvas Unity3D разные слои

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал Canvas, добавил Image, растянул. Получилось хорошо, только перекрывает все объекты вне канваса.
Переставил значения в Canvas Renderer Screen Space Camera  - получился прекрасный задний план. Но UI кнопки теперь тоже на заднем плане. И теперь всё что не на канвасе - то на переднем плане.

Вопрос - как разделить элементы Canvas-а таким образом, чтобы какие то были дальше от зрителя чем объекты вне канваса, а какие то - на переднем плане, Screen Overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё до банальности просто - создаем второй Canvas, диктуем там свои правила и переносим туда нужные объекты.

Comment: а разве если переместить объект ниже в иерархии канваса он не выплывет на передний план? Вроде бы должен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Всплывет, но только относительно других компонентов там же. А если нужно чтобы одни были выше объектов НЕ не канвасе, а другие ниже этих объектов - то никак.

Comment: Что-то я не увидел где в вашем вопросе фигурируют объекты НЕ не канвасе. Я бы рекомендовал на будущее более ясно излагать, возможно прикладывать скрины. А то они какие-то то размытые и непонятные, то странные)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо! Исправил, теперь всё более ясно.

Comment: @Dmitrii на самом деле можно. Это длинная история с настройкой слоев и дополнительной камеры, но сделать объекты сцены поверх канваса можно. Если интересно, то я такое уже делал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480971/unity2d-layering-multiple-canvas/